# Xcode use GHUnit command line failed with exit code 139

Tags: ios, xcode, gh-unit

I create a project with using GHUnit. However, when I use GHUnit `make test` command to execute, an error occurs like this:

```
Running: "/Users/gongtao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MicIOSHelper-eqvmgnulwgjftjfnkcrzkpwkyefw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MicIOSHelper.app/MicIOSHelper" -RegisterForSystemEvents
RunTests.sh: line 50:  8604 Segmentation fault: 11  "/Users/gongtao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MicIOSHelper-eqvmgnulwgjftjfnkcrzkpwkyefw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MicIOSHelper.app/MicIOSHelper" -RegisterForSystemEvents
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 139

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/gongtao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MicIOSHelper-eqvmgnulwgjftjfnkcrzkpwkyefw/Build/Intermediates/MicIOSHelper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MicIOSHelper.build/Script-42D16A2D1A1476C3007976D9.sh
(1 failure)
make: *** [test] Error 65
```

I follow this guidelines: [GHUnit Running From Command Line](https://github.com/gh-unit/gh-unit/blob/master/Documentation/appledoc_include/guide_command_line-template.markdown)

The makefile is like this:

```
clean:
    -rm -rf build/*
test:
    GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild -target Tests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator build
```

My project name is 'MicIOSHelper'.

Comment: I think that's an old way. Do you have a xcworkspace file ?

Comment: Well, the script is failing with a segmentation fault, you should ask it on a github issue https://github.com/gh-unit/gh-unit/